# Call Oracle function from Java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, stored-functions

I have following function specification:

```
FUNCTION FUNC_GET_SOMETHING_FROM_DATABASE ( IN_parameter1           IN VARCHAR2,
                                            IN_parameter2           IN VARCHAR2,
                                            IN_parameter3           IN VARCHAR2,
                                            IN_parameter4           IN VARCHAR2,
                                            IN_parameter5           IN VARCHAR2,
                                            IN_parameter6           IN VARCHAR2) 

RETURN REFCURTYP;
```

Following is my method in Java that is calling the function in Oracle:

```
public List<SomeVO> getLogReport(
            String parameter1, String parameter2, String parameter3,
            String parameter4, String parameter5,
            String parameter6) throws BlahException, RemoteDataAccessException {

        Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();

        DataCollectionImpl<LogReportVO> someData = new DataCollectionImpl<LogReportVO>(
                LogReportVO.class);

                // IN Parameters

        params.add(parameter1);
        params.add(parameter2);
        params.add(parameter3);
        params.add(parameter4);
        params.add(parameter5);
        params.add(parameter6);


        //Out Parameter
        params.add(new DBParameter(DBParameter.OUT, DBParameter.CURSOR));

        try {
            callStoredProcedure(
                    Constants.FUNC_GET_SOMETHING_FROM_DATABASE, params);
        } catch (RemoteDataAccessException e) {
            throw new BlahException("LogReportDAO",
                    "getLogReport", e.getMessage(),
                    e.getRealException());
        }
        return someData.getDataCollectionObjects();
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
wrong number or types of arguments in call
```

Additional Information:

```
protected void callStoredProcedure(String procedureName, Vector params) throws RemoteDataAccessException {
        callStoredProcedure(getSchema(), procedureName, params);
    }

    protected void callStoredProcedure(String schema, String procedureName, Vector params) throws RemoteDataAccessException {
        callStoredProcedure(getDatasource(), schema, procedureName, params);
    }

    protected void callStoredProcedure(String dataSourceName, String schema, String procedureName, Vector params) throws RemoteDataAccessException {
        getOracleConnection(dataSourceName).callStoredProcedure(
                getFullyQualifiedProcedureName(schema, procedureName), params);
    }

    private OracleConnection getOracleConnection(String datasource) {   
        OracleConnection oraConn = null;
        try {   
            oraConn = new OracleConnection(datasource); 
        } catch (RemoteDataAccessException rdae) {  
            log.fatal("BaseDAO.getOracleConnection " + rdae.getMessage(), rdae);
        } catch (Exception ie) {    
            log.fatal("BaseDAO.getOracleConnection" + ie.getMessage(), ie);
        }

        return oraConn;
    }
```

Comment: ever think about using a wrapper for JDBC, like Mybatis3.  It makes life easier when working with complex types. http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/

Comment: You are right but right now time is the factor so I dont think that would be possible. I think I am having a problem with the OUT parameter. Do you know any way to get around this?

Comment: I don't really.  I know all of this possible with MyBatis.  Out parameters are just set into the field on the parameter object.  Sorry I couldn't come up with an answer for you.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what you do in callStoredProcedure()?

Comment: Added info about callStoredProcedure()

Comment: The Oracle JDBC driver includes an interface named `OracleConnection` and an abstract class named `OracleConnection`, but not, so far as I can see, a concrete class named `OracleConnection`. So your use of `new OracleConnection(datasource)` suggests that you're still not showing the relevant code . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your code is not taking into account stored procedure return value.

Why not to use standard JDBC way of calling stored procedure instead? It works like a charm.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/callablestatement.html

Comment: Thanks people for your support but I made it work. I just called the function inside a Stored Procedure and it worked. I had that thought before but for some reason I think I didn't try harder.

Comment: You are right but the thing is we are using a certain design pattern and I didn't want to violate it. No one thought before that we might end up using table objects and thus we never exposed such a utility that would make a direct function call easier.